# How to reset kendo.ui.RangeSlider to initial value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-slider

I have implemented the angular js version of `kendo.ui.RangeSlider`. Below is my code.

**HTML**

```
 <div kendo-range-slider="fbaSlider" k-options="fba">
```

**Angular Code**

```
    $scope.fbaStart = 0;
    $scope.fbaEnd = 0;
    $scope.fba = {

    min: 0,
    max: 18,
    smallStep: 1,
    largeStep: 2,
    tickPlacement: "both",
    change: function (e) {
        $scope.fbaStart = e.value[0];
        $scope.fbaEnd = e.value[1];

    }
}
```

As you can see I have set `kendo-range-slider="fbaSlider"` in my HTML so I have a reference to the Slider object in my scope and I can access that as `$scope.fbaSlider`

What I want is to have a button on the page and on its click I want to reset the slider to its initial position.

I tried something like `$scope.fbaSlider.options.selectionStart=0`. But this did not work. What am I doing wrong. Let me know if any other information is required.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use value or values method.

```
$scope.fbaSlider.value([0,18]);
```

or

```
$scope.fbaSlider.values(0,18);
```